# Cannot convert `float*' to `float' for argument `1' to `float summ(float, int)'

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток!

Дали задание написать программу, которая считает сумму однородного массива **float**, кроме одного числа.

И я столкнулся с такой проблемой, которая указана в заголовке темы: Cannot convert `float* to float for argument 1 to float summ(float, int)`

Как быть?
Заранее спасибо за ответы и помощь!

---

Дабы вопросу просто так не висеть на сайте, такой вопрос: как можно улучшить код? Раз уже с глупым предыдущим вопросом разобрались.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

float summ(float array, int k); //объявление функции.

main(){
  float array[10], sumarr; //объявление массива.
  int i, k;

  for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){ //вводим массив
    printf("array[%d]: ", i);
    scanf("%f", &array[i]);
  }

  printf("\nEnter K: "); //вводим позицию ограничивающего слова
  scanf("%d", &k);

  sumarr = summ(array, k); //эта функция считает сумму до и после числа, которое не нужно считать.

  printf("\n\nSummarr = %f", sumarr); //выводит результат

  getch();
}

float summ(float *array, int k){
  int i;
  float sumarray;

  for(i = 0; i < k; i++){ //считаем до ограничивающего числа
    sumarray += array[i];
  }

  for(i = k + 1; i < 10; i++){ //считаем после ограничивающего числа
    sumarray += array[i];
  }

  return (sumarray);
}
```

Comment: @DrummerIF, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float summ(float array, int k); //объявление функции.
float summ(float *array, int k){
```

Задача на банальное нахождение разницы в двух строках

Comment: @Etki ох... И вправду, спасибо, что-то голова совсем не работает.